# dnsruby - error fetching TXT records but not MX records for some domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns

How come with certain domains, I can fetch MX records just fine, but fetching TXT records I get a 'Dnsruby::NXDomain' error?

Example:

This throws a Dnsruby::NXDomain error:

```
DNS.new.getresources("kimcorealty.com", Types.TXT)
```

This works perfectly for the same domain:

```
DNS.new.getresources("kimcorealty.com", Types.MX)
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

I found where the error is happening in the Ruby source.

At this line: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/resolv.rb#L529

Here's the state of the response when I'm on that line. You can see we're failing that conditional, returning an error. However, if I look at the reply before this, all the TXT records I want are right there.

```
[7] pry(#<Resolv::DNS>)> reply

=> #<Resolv::DNS::Message:0x00007fd261cb28f8
 @aa=0,
 @additional=[],
 @answer=
  [[#<Resolv::DNS::Name: kimcorealty.com.>, 1020, #<Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT:0x00007fd261c89638 @strings=["MS=ms98433547"], @ttl=1020>],
   [#<Resolv::DNS::Name: kimcorealty.com.>, 1020, #<Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT:0x00007fd261c72578 @strings=["docusign=69340a61-0fcc-46b8-b7a9-2d49a40007c3"], @ttl=1020>],
   [#<Resolv::DNS::Name: kimcorealty.com.>,
    1020,
    #<Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT:0x00007fd261c5b490
     @strings=
      ["v=spf1 ip4:167.206.63.136 ip4:64.238.213.254 ip4:66.77.249.235 ip4:66.77.249.236 ip4:216.203.55.53 ip4:216.203.55.54 ip4:209.114.43.188 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:spf-00297101.pphosted.com ~all"],
     @ttl=1020>],
   [#<Resolv::DNS::Name: kimcorealty.com.>,
    1020,
    #<Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT:0x00007fd261c483e0 @strings=["atlassian-domain-verification=vA/K8uyQPRi6pNbTDb5/Hu/yk900zY28QlEtwyrwRs8bKY/N7UG27xsGA8eLjS1V"], @ttl=1020>]],
 @authority=[],
 @id=27795,
 @opcode=0,
 @qr=1,
 @question=[[#<Resolv::DNS::Name: kimcorealty.com.>, Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT]],
 @ra=1,
 @rcode=0,
 @rd=1,
 @tc=1>


[8] pry(#<Resolv::DNS>)> reply.tc

=> 1

[9] pry(#<Resolv::DNS>)> requester

=> #<Resolv::DNS::Requester::UnconnectedUDP:0x00007fd262172708
 @nameserver_port=[["192.168.0.1", 53], ["192.168.0.1", 53]],
 @senders=
  {[["192.168.0.1", 53], 27795]=>
    #<Resolv::DNS::Requester::UnconnectedUDP::Sender:0x00007fd25ef3e200
     @data=#<Resolv::DNS::Name: kimcorealty.com.>,
     @host="192.168.0.1",
     @msg="l\x93\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\vkimcorealty\x03com\x00\x00\x10\x00\x01",
     @port=53,
     @sock=#<UDPSocket:fd 8, AF_INET, 0.0.0.0, 45796>>},
 @socks=[#<UDPSocket:fd 8, AF_INET, 0.0.0.0, 45796>],
 @socks_hash={"0.0.0.0"=>#<UDPSocket:fd 8, AF_INET, 0.0.0.0, 45796>}>
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you reproduce the NXDomain error with other domains? Are you sure your nameserver(s) are working properly?

Comment: @tadman Yes, about 1 out of 50 or so.

Comment: If I put the same domain into mxtoolbox.com I get the MX and TXT records.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug in the Ruby library, or your DNS server being really broken. Can you reproduce the issue with `dig`?

Comment: @tadman I can get the txt records just fine for this domain with dig.

Comment: It works for me using [this code](https://gist.github.com/tadman/b849a9e3b9f8002a2c8569bcee987899) which is substantially different from yours despite using the same Resolv library. I'd check how you're using it.

Comment: @tadman I have that exact code and it fails. Ugh

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your local DNS. Have you tried using 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1?

Comment: Yep, it works when I run it from a remote server.

Comment: Yes! It works when I use 8.8.8.8! Thanks!!